# Why :last-child doesn't work when we have more elements inside?

Tags: css, css-selectors

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/jwmCd/

HTML

```
<div class="round-buttons">
                <a href="#">hello</a>
                <a href="#">world</a>
    <form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.round-buttons a:first-child {background:red}

.round-buttons a:last-child {background:green}
```

`.round-buttons a:last-child {background:green}` is not applying in this condition.

Dynamically there could be more links and I want to give different styling to First and last Anchor.

Answer (score 23):

`:last-child` will only match the last element of the parent, irrespective of its type (in your example, `:last-child` will only match the `<input>`). Use `:last-of-type` to match the last element of a specific type in the parent, for example:

```
.round-buttons a:last-of-type {background:green}
```

Comment: but Dynamically there could be more links and I want to give different styling to First and last Anchor. So think only solution is @Hurda answer

Comment: `a:last-of-type` will only match the last anchor.

Comment: `:last-of-type` is not supported by IE 8 and earlier. The most cross-browser way is to use classes.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: If he's already using `:last-child`, I don't think IE8's lack of support for either pseudo-class bothers him.

Comment: @BoltClock, when generating the links, it should be easy to add a `class` attribute to avoid using `:last-child` too.

Answer (score 4):

Because `a` is not the last child, the last child is `form`

Answer (score 3):

In this example the `<a href="#">world</a>` is not last child of parent element `<div class="round-buttons">` - last child of this element is `<input name="q" ... >`

The :first-child and :last-child selector doesn¨t take into account element type - all elements are equal.
You can put your  tags into div or span

see http://jsfiddle.net/jwmCd/4/

Answer (score 0):

The form is the last object.
You can put the links in a separate div and call the last-child from that one.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <!-- LINKS HERE -->
    </div>
    <form></form>
</div>
```